# Looking for a simple and better way to select a value from a lot of users mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to select all post from user 1,2,3,4,5,6. How can I do it in a simple and better way. I don't want to write 6 times where user_id equal one by one. I am afraid that will slow web speed also.

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT post FROM $table WHERE user_id='1,2,3,4,5,6'";
?>
```

Comment: Try IN keyword to get all record of user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT post FROM $table WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)";
?>
```

This will return all post of user_id (1,2...6).

Answer (score 1):

In-case you deal with range, another alternative is to use `BETWEEN`.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT post FROM $table WHERE user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 6";
?>
```

This will return all post of user_id 1 to 6.